# How to map an Object with TypeScript - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My goal is to list the categories names (prospecting and estimate in this case)

New with TypeScript, i'm trying to map this Object :

```
{
    "categories": {
        "prospecting": {
            "name": "Nos offres",
            "products": {
                "product1": {
                    "service": "Le pack",
                    "title": "Le pack",
                    "description": "Un accompagnement unique à 360° au service de votre performance.  erat nibh, tristique quis augue ac, egestas porttitor mauris-",
                    "redirect": "/accueil"
                },
                "product2": {
                    "service": "Nouveauté",
                    "title": "Le pack 2",
                    "description": "Vestibulum erat nibh, tristique quis augue ac, egestas porttitor mauris-",
                    "redirect": "/accueil"
                }
            }
        },
        "estimate": {
            "name": "Nos offres",
            "products": {
                "product1": {
                    "service": "Le pack",
                    "title": "Le pack",
                    "description": "Un accompagnement unique à 360° au service de votre performance.  erat nibh, tristique quis augue ac, egestas porttitor mauris-",
                    "redirect": "/accueil"
                },
                "product2": {
                    "service": "Nouveauté",
                    "title": "Le pack 2",
                    "description": "Vestibulum erat nibh, tristique quis augue ac, egestas porttitor mauris-",
                    "redirect": "/accueil"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my attempt :

```
export default function Filters(props: any) {
    const [listOfCategories, setListOfCategories] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        const listOfCategories = props.categories.map(category => {
            setListOfCategories(category)
        })
        console.log(listOfCategories)
    })
```

but VSCode underline in red "category" `map` function and says :
`Parameter 'category' implicitly has an 'any' type`

Anyone can help me to solve this ?

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: You should have an interface for your object, it's safer and the compiler won't blame for mapping a key of an object that is known for the typescript.

Comment: Where should I put this interface ? After the return ?

Comment: you should learn about typescript interfaces and that would make your job easier

Comment: Ok, I will tonight then. Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome, it should be a bit frustrating at the first steps, but keep it up and best wishes for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are expecting an object without getting the data from api call it's enough to get it like this:

```
const [listOfCategories, setListOfCategories] = useState(
 Object.keys(props.categories)
);
```

Or inside useEffect like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
const categoriesList = Object.keys(props.categories);
setListOfCategories(categoriesList)
console.log(categoriesList)
}, [props.categories]);
```